# How to make the space between views grow when given a large frame, but be as small as possible otherwise?

Tags: swiftui, layout

This question is essentially about how to define layout behaviour for a SwiftUI View such that it grows/shrinks in a particular way when given different frames *externally*. IE imagine you are creating a View which will be packaged up in a library and given to somebody else, without you knowing how much space they will give to your view.

The layout I would like to create will contain two horizontal views, indicated by `A` & `B` in my diagrams. I would like to control how this view expands if you specify a frame like follows:

- When no frame is specified, I'd like my container View to be as small as the inner views and no bigger. See **diagram 1**.
- When the container View is given a frame that's larger than the inner views, I'd like the space between the inner views to grow. See **diagram 2**.

**Diagram 1**: How I'd like my View to look without a frame specified.

```
// MyView()

|       [A B]       |
```

**Diagram 2**: How I'd like my View to look with a large frame.

```
// MyView().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

|[A               B]|
```

Diagram Key:

- `|` represents my Window
- `[]` represents my container View
- `A` and `B` are my child Views.

---

My naive attempts:

**Unmodified HStack**
The behaviour of an unmodified `HStack` matches Diagram 1 with an unspecified frame successfully, however when given a large frame it's default behaviour is to grow as follows:

```
// HStack{A B}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
|[        AB       ]|
```

**HStack with a Spacer between the views**
If I use a Stack with but add a spacer in between the views, the spacer grows to take up the most space possible, regardless of what frame is given. IE I end up with a view that looks like Diagram 2 even when no frame is specified.

```
// HStack{A Spacer B}

|[A               B]|
```

I've been trying to figure out a way to tell a Spacer to prefer to be as small as possible, but to no avail. What other options do we have to achieve this layout?

---

Edit: To help out, here's some code as a starting point:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var largeFrame: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Toggle("Large Frame", isOn: $largeFrame)
            
            HStack {
                Text("A")
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                
                Text("B")
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: largeFrame ? .infinity : nil)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "spacer grows to take up the most space possible immediately" - it exactly means that "consumer of my View gives it a large frame".

Comment: `frame(maxWidth: largeFrame ? .infinity : nil)` - there is no diffs here, providing .infinity or nil is the same

Comment: @Asperi To clarify, I mean that I could add a spacer inside my view, but it causes the view to have a large frame. I want other people who are using my view to control what frame size it gets, whether that be small or large. 

IE I want to control how my view grows, while keeping it as small as possible by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused to what you are saying. Are you asking how to generate space between `A` and `B` without forcing the HStack to be window width? If so, if you place a frame on the HStack, then the spacer shoulder only separate the contents to as far as the user desires?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("A")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("B")
        }
        .frame(width: 100)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Does the following code work? The `HStack(spacing: 0)` ensures that the contents the HStack have no spacing between the items and so the "smallest" possible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var customSpacing = true
    @State private var customFrame = CGFloat(100)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                customSpacing.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Custom or Not")
            }

            if !customSpacing {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("A")
                    
                    Text("B")
                }
            } else {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("A")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("B")
                }
                .frame(width: customFrame)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 

I want my view to be as small as possible by default, ie it will be the size of A + B and no more. 

However if somebody else comes along, imports my view to use, and then adds a frame modifier at their call site, - In this situation I want the space between A and B to grow so that it looks like my second diagram. 

Hope this helps clarify, please let me know if I can update the question to be clearer in any way.

Comment: @user1636130 I just edited my answer. Does that help in any way?

Comment: That achieves the effect I'm after but it relies on me having knowledge about whether or not somebody has applied custom spacing to my View or not. 

Imagine you were packaging up this view to ship in a library and you didn't know who was going to use it or where!

Comment: @user1636130 This should be another question. Please mark this one answered and ask a seperate question.

Comment: Sorry but you've not answered my question. My question is specifically about defining behaviour internally so a desired layout is achieved when a frame is specified on the externally. If there's something I could do to make that more clear in my original question please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If `MyView` is your component and you have control over its content, then a possible approach is to "override" `.frame` modifiers (all of them, below is one for demo) and compare explicitly outer width provided by `frame` and inner width of content subviews.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main parts:

```
struct MyView: View {         // << your component
    var outerWidth: CGFloat?  // << injected width !!

    @State private var myWidth = CGFloat.zero // << own calculated !!
        // ...
```

"overridden" frame modifier to store externally provided parameter

```
@inlinable public func frame(minWidth: CGFloat? = nil, idealWidth: CGFloat? = nil, maxWidth: CGFloat? = nil, minHeight: CGFloat? = nil, idealHeight: CGFloat? = nil, maxHeight: CGFloat? = nil, alignment: Alignment = .center) -> some View {
    var newview = self
    newview.outerWidth = maxWidth   // << inject frame width !!

    return VStack { newview }   // << container to avoid cycling !!
       .frame(minWidth: minWidth, idealWidth: idealWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth, minHeight: minHeight, idealHeight: idealHeight, maxHeight: maxHeight, alignment: alignment)
}
```

and conditionally activated space depending on width diffs

```
SubViewA()
.background(GeometryReader {
    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewSideLengthKey.self,
        value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
})

if let width = outerWidth, width > myWidth {    // << here !!
    Spacer()
}

SubViewB()
.background(GeometryReader {
    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewSideLengthKey.self,
        value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
})
```

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestOuterFrameHandling.swift)